# Passing action link value from partial view to view

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

In my view I have a section

```
<div id="AssNameSection" style="display: none;">
      <div id="AssNameSectionLoad"></div>
</div>
```

and there is a bit of jquery which shows and opens a partial view in that section when a check box is ticked.

```
...
$("#AssNameSectionLoad").load(newurl);
```

this all works.  In the sub section that has been loaded is some row data with an action link and the row ID as the ID.

I'm trying to pass that ID of the row click to the main view for editing.

I figure out how to use the `.click` to capture an action link in another form/view/section.

Is this possible, can anyone point my in the right direction please?

EDIT more info

action link code in the partial view being rendered in the assnamesectionload div

```
 <td class="ActionLinks">                             
                        @Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName",
                         new { controller = "MyController", id = item.id },
                         new { @class = "my-class" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
```

html section

```
    <div id="AssNameSection" style="">
                            <div id="AssNameSectionLoad">

<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="Zt9MlOm1zFuV_oAihoql_9aT-ch2fVkRs2oHodR1wCZkpMuhwLQHMS8_RTSRRcSCYBFlNa7psrVLu1-xhxAmc-jzhppX0UfbZ3gvzn62TQaJxtzpu4T_j3NtRXy2e6yH0">    <div>


        <div>
            <table class="table">

                <tbody><tr>
                    <th>
                        Relationship
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Associated Name 
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Options
                    </th>                    
                </tr>

<input id="txtAssNameLineid" name="item.id" type="hidden" value="12157PAR121600">                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            yyy
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            xxx
                        </td>

                        <td class="ActionLinks">                             
                            <a class="my-class" href="/MyController/ActionName/12157PAR121600">Link Text</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

            </tbody></table>

        </div>
    </div>


</div>
                        </div>
```

jquery

```
<script>
    $("a.my-class", "#AssNameSectionLoad").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("a my-class has been clicked");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a button in the row for click or a click event is raised on clicking on row element? What is the row parent? is it a table?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have an entrypoint for the jquery selector you can use the `.click` function. 
Let's say there is a `$('.clickable')` withing the `$("#AssNameSectionLoad")` element (which you might generate in a partial view or whatever).
you can then use `$('.clickable', '#AssNameSectionLoad').click(function(){...})` to handle behaviour.

The basic concept is that your jquery will look at the final html, not the html within the view where you've put it.

EDIT:

To select the id of the input element, you could use this jquery:

```
$("a.my-class", "#AssNameSectionLoad").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').prev('input').attr('id');
    alert("a my-class has been clicked id="+id);
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqr9845t/1/) with the code.

Comment: thanks, think i followed what you are saying but cant get it working. have updated with more info if you don't mind taking a look?

Comment: I hope my edit helps, If you want to select another id please specify

Comment: just to clarify in case i haven't explained correctly.  The jquery is in my main view to capture the change in the subsection i load from a partial view.

tried you script bit like mine it doesn't capture the click and prevent the load, it tries to load the link and fails with an invalid url.

Comment: the url is meant to be invalid, as i want to prevent the load and capture in jquery which i will then set another value to be that captured one to load some options.